# How to select all records year to date in oracle?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a table with a field create_date (unix-timestamp). How can I select all records of the past 12 months?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Past 12 months or YTD? Those are different things...

Comment: Oh yea? What the difference?

Comment: As of today (March 11th, 2015), generally YTD=January 1st 2015 - March 11th 2015. Past 12 months = February 1st 2014 - February 28th 2014, or maybe even March 12th, 2014 - March 11th 2015. People like to define these different ways.

Comment: Thank you, I mixed something up then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like the following. Keep in mind that Unix timestamps represent the number of seconds passed since midnight on January 1, 1970:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE date'1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(create_date, 'SECOND') >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12));
```

I'm guessing that the value of `create_date` is somewhere in the area of 1,400,000,000.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert UNIX Timestamp to date format, then use ADD_MONTHS even to subtract them.

-- SQL to see and verify the dates

```
select ADD_MONTHS(MYTABLE.CREATE_DATE, -12) from MYTABLE;
```

-- SQL to use to answer your question

```
select *
from MYTABLE
where MYTABLE.CREATE_DATE > ADD_MONTHS(SYSTIMESTAMP, -12);
```

Comment: So you mean select * from mytable where create_date > ADD_MONTHS(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'DD/MM/YYYY'), -12) ?

Comment: That's an odd way to do it ... why are you converting to char?

Comment: Sorry, conversion to CHAR was a vestige of my tests. Now is corrected and updated.